# Have Blockchain.info (intentionally) removed the option to directly exchange BCH into BTC/ETH?

Tags: blockchain.info, exchanges, bitcoin-cash

An article on the Blockchain Support Center documents [Exchanging bitcoin cash (BCH) for bitcoin (BTC) or ethereum (ETH)](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005177623-Exchanging-bitcoin-cash-BCH-for-bitcoin-BTC-or-ethereum-ETH-), with the following screenshot:

> [image: Bitcoin Cash balance example]

Since Monday, I've been unable to see the *Exchange Bitcoin Cash* option in my own wallet:

> [image: My own wallet example]

On Tuesday I reached out to @AskBlockchain on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/inb4/status/932965388899508230), but so far I've had no response.

Has Blockchain.info has removed this option completely or is this simply a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was an issue with my home WiFi blocking some of Blockchain.info's API calls. Not sure why, mind you, but connecting to a different network allowed me to see those options again.